# Getting out of bounds exception, cant figure out exactly why though

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, bubble-sort

I'm making a program that takes an integer array and sorts it using "bubble sorting" (switching adjacent numbers until its in order.) I've been trying to figure out exactly why i'm getting this out of bounds error, but it still doesn't make much sense to me since arrays are still a pretty new concept for me.

```
public static boolean onePass(int[] a) {
    boolean ordered = true;
    for (int i = 0; i+1 < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
            ordered = false;
            return ordered;
    } }
    return ordered;
}
public static void printArray(int[] b) { 
    for(int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){ 
    System.out.println(i + "   " + b[i]); 
    }
}
public static int[] bubbleSort(int[] unsorted) {
    int[] a = unsorted;
    boolean sorted = false;
    for (int i = 0; sorted == true; i++) {
    sorted = onePass(a);
        if (i > a.length) {
            i = 0;    
        }
        if (a[i] < a[i+1] && i < a.length) {
            swapElement(a, i, i + 1);
            //System.out.println(i + " " + (i+1));
    } 
    }
    return a;
    }
```

The onePass method is supposed to check to see if its in order.

Im getting: "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25"
at this line: if (a[i] < a[i+1] && i < a.length)

Sorry if this is a super dumb question
Im in a class learning java, so there may be a more efficient way to make this program, but using what we have learned so far this is what i'm able to understand and write myself.

EDIT: The array that i am sorting has 25 numbers (0-24) in a text document that i read with a BufferedReader.

EDIT 2: Found a way more efficient way to bubble sort, ended up commenting all this out, but thanks for the help!

Comment: If an array is declared as `new int[3]`, how many and which indices does it have? What happens when you do `a[i+1]`? What is the last value `i` can take?

Comment: `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:25` means you're trying to access the element at index 25.  For an array to have an index of 25 in bounds, it must contain at least 26 elements (you even point out that you understand this 0-based indexing concept: `The array that i am sorting has 25 numbers (0-24)`)

Comment: I understand what the error means, but i dont understand why its going beyond i = 23 making i+1=24.

Comment: Try debugging. It's a great tool.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that `i + 1` isn't going out of bounds.

At this line here, do the `i < a.length` check before accessing `a[i]`, and similarly, add a check *before* you try to access `a[i+1]`:

```
if (i < a.length && /* check i+1 */ && a[i] < a[i+1])
```

Since this is homework, I'll let you fill in the actual code.

Comment: What do you mean by check i+1?

Comment: Check that the array is large enough for there to actually be a cell at index `i+1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're going beyond the last element in the array.

Because you're checking that `i` is no greater than or equal to length, but `a[i+1]` will make it equal to the length, as the array is 0 indexed it will reach one element after the last.

Try this:

```
if (i >= a.length-1) {
    i = 0;    
}
else if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
    swapElement(a, i, i + 1);
    System.out.println(i + " " + (i+1));
}
```

**EDIT**

You also have the same problem in your third line:

```
for (int i = 0; i+1 < a.length; i++) {
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i+1 < a.length-1; i++) {
```

because of the next line:

```
if (a[i] < a[i+1]) {
```

**EDIT2**

When you make `i` not bigger or equal to `a.length` and `a.length` is 25, `i` will be up to 24, when `i` is 24 the `a+1` will be 25, out of bounds so.

Answer (score 0):

In the line in question, try replacing this :

```
a[i] < a[i+1] && i < a.length
```

with:

```
i < a.length && a[i] < a[i+1]
```

At probably the last iteration, you still try to access an element `i+1` before you ensure it is smaller than the length of your array. So in that case, you get a `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.